Why weren't there games that use CGA 16-color low res mode?
The very first PC could do stuff only seen in arcade games, like graphics mode vertical scrolling.

It involved a little known 160 x 100 video mode called  "lores" that was almost undocumented in by IBM.
In fact, I got a free EGA Wonder card because they guaranteed it was 100% CGA compatible, and when I wrote them about low res mode, they refunded my money. I didn't think I should tell anybody because otherwise all EGA wonder cards would have to be refunded. By the way, would that have been an actual possibility?

Yet I don't remember a single commercial game that used this video mode which could even emulate Pacman (though I did find these screenshots). My question is, why weren't there more (or any) commercial 16 color CGA games?
Probably, 4x color was a lot less valuable than double xy resolution.

That's a pretty cool mode, I didn't even know it existed. As for "why weren't there any games", my guess is (1) nobody really thought of it back then, (2) no BIOS support, (3) doesn't work on EGA etc., (4) snow artifacts during access, are probably good enough reasons...

https://github.com/dschmenk/LORES for some details.

hey thanx @dirkt that explained it all!

@dirkt (1) LoRes mode was mentioned first in the list of possible modes in IBM CGA documentation, along with notes how to do it so the info was there (2) indeed there is no BIOS support for many things that are possible in hardware and that has not stopped people using hardware outside BIOS (3) Why would it not work on EGA etc, the Pacman game in the screenshot worked fine on VGA card in same CGA tweak mode. It's a standard 200-line text mode with character cells set to 2 lines instead of 8. The CRTC Max Scan Line register 0x09 are that much compatible between cards.

@Justme Indeed, IBM documentation included that the 160x100/16 color modes exists, but it did not include sufficient info "how to do so". I'm looking at the IBM Personal Computer Technical Reference, 1st edition. The mode is mentioned on page 2-51 in "Table 4". There is a hint on page 2-59: "The low resolution 160 x 100 mode requires special programming and is set up as alpha mode 40 x 25". The version of the low res mode that actually got used is a 80 x 100 alpha mode, though. While the hint likely is only meant for the mode register programming (which does not care about the ...

... text row count, so x25 or x100 doesn't make any difference), the mode needs to be set to 80x25, not 40x25. The CRTC programming for 100 text rows of two scan lines instead of 25 text rows of 8 scan lines is completely left as an exercise for the reader.

@Justme Furthermore, low-res CGA software (I had a breakout clone) did not work out-of-the-box on EGA/VGA. One reason is that the way to disable blinking background is different. Another reason is that shrinking the character height to 2 scan lines indeed does work, but on VGA you shrink from 16 to 2 lines, which would yield an 80 x 200 text mode instead of the desired 80 x 100 text mode.

@MichaelKarcher Thanks so obviously the note is incorrect as everywhere else it is made clear that the 160x100 mode has 2x2 PELs implying 80x25 text mode. The mode is simply set on CGA by setting 8 lines per char to 2 lines per char, the amount of text rows grows automatically. On VGA indeed you may need to go to 200-line doublescanned text mode with 8x8 char cells first. On EGA you might need to go to 200-line 8x8 cell text mode, by telling the card you have a CGA monitor attached so it does not output 350 lines in EGA text mode.

@Justme No, the amount of text rows does not grow automatically on CGA. It does on EGA and VGA. The 6845 CRTC on the CGA card counts the vertical cycle in text rows, not in scanlines. Any application using the 160x100 mode needs to fully reprogram the vertical cycle control registers on the CGA. On EGA/VGA, the CRTC indices that are used by the 6845 for programming the vertical cycle are write protected by default, so CGA software can't mess up the timing. The text row counting operation of the 6845 CRTC with its 7-bit text row counter is the reason we have banked CGA graphics memory...

... as the 6845 is unable to linearly scan 200 logical lines. Instead the "second bank" for the odd lines is "the second scanline of the (text) row" in the way the 6845 looks at it. So the vertical cycle for the 160x100 mode is programmed like in graphics mode, while the horizontal cycle is programmed like in 80-column text mode.

@MichaelKarcher Sorry you are absolutely correct - height is set in character rows indeed. The table with register settings does come in handy when setting a mix&match of the modes.

They refunded your money?  Those were the days...

I remember asking this exact question 35+ years ago. The mode was kind of chunky-looking, but head-and-shoulders above that cyan/magenta BS. Was always really disgusted by that mode, especially given that I'd given away or mothballed non-PC-compatible machines that could do much better. The "new, powerful PC-compatible" computer I'd lusted after, well... it did have a nice keyboard and a very loud BEEP.

I was confused by your first sentence until I realized you meant "IBM PC" and not the first personal computer of any brand. Maybe I'm the only one.

@ToddWilcox I didn't put it that way because "IBM PC" would have excluded PC compatibles, which most of the PCs were.

The very first PC-compatible PC was made by IBM themselves. Are you saying that you meant to write "the very first PCs"? Either way it would make sense to say "IBM-compatible" somewhere in there since there were tons of personal computers in the early 80s that were not IBM compatible.

When you say PC, you're generally not talking about the Mac. Or the amiga. Or the thing that kid had in War Games.

@ToddWilcox, PC wasn't used by the masses back in the 80's as an abbreviation for personal computer, it was used for the IBM machine and their derivatives and compatibles. There were many personal computers around in those early years but relatively very few of the the general public came into contact with them, and with  that term, until the IBM PC and clones took off, all under the name 'PC'.

@TonyM I was one of the masses back then and I remember it differently. As in “what kind of PC do you have?” “It’s an Apple ][“. It’s possible this was regional or something. Like today there are places where you can overhear: “what kind of coke do you want?” “A Pepsi.”

@ToddWilcox, maybe it was a regional thing, like you say. I was around then and never heard anyone using PC, or personal computer much. It was just 'my computer', or 'home computer' if it was. Never heard the coke one  but I take your point, thinking Hoover instead of vacuum cleaner or iPad instead of tablet.

"only seen in arcade games, like graphics mode vertical scrolling"
The Commodore 64 and Atari 8-bits had hardware scrolling.

I think I mostly saw color text-mode games instead of this.

Such games do exist. Wikipedia article on CGA has at least these examples

Moon Bugs by IBM 1983
Icon: Quest for the Ring by Macrocom 1984
The Seven Spirits of Ra by Macrocom 1987

Likely more can be found by searching on Mobygames for games with a tag "CGA (Tweaked)", but it lists all tweaks, not just this specific tweak.
Why there was no much interest for that mode is more difficult to answer.
It is likely that the lower resolution was an artistic issue compared to how good looking CGA games could be in the standard 320x200 four colour mode with any of the selectable palettes and background colours, or in 320x200 four colour or 640x200 two colour mode with composite output to a TV that can show the intermediate artifact colors.
If a game assets and engine are already made for e.g. 320x200 16 color mode, it might be not worth the time and money to support a 160x100 mode on CGA, as often it's about the whole machine. It is simpler to just use the same 320x200 with hastily made CGA assets.
You may expect to see machines with a 286 CPU and an EGA card but rarely a CGA. For CGA there likely is a 8088 and no EGA.
And it also depends on the game type, if it uses a lot of CPU power it may choose to use more powerful instructions available on a faster 286 than on a slower 8088.
Including several assets also makes a game larger, which may mean it might not fit onto a floppy and may require installing on a hard drive.
So the 16-color 160x100 mode just was not very useful, considering what can be done with it, and where the market was going with 286/EGA machines.

Hey, thanx! moonbugs gameplay. They traded horrible screen resolution for a lot of colors they didn't use. Could have had double resolution in 4 color cga medres.

Indeed, the 320x200 graphics mode relying on artifact color mixing is a very strong contender to the 160x100 graphics mode. Take for example https://www.mobygames.com/game/76/shamus/screenshots/pc-booter/184/ (RGB) vs https://www.mobygames.com/game/76/shamus/screenshots/pc-booter/864629/ (composite). Look at the nice solid red and blue colored "legs" of the "spiral drone" enemies in the composite display. I never understood why CGA games often had these vertical stripes when playing them on a VGA system. Since learning about artifact colors, I do.

OMG, that's where the vertical stripes come from? God! That's what happens when you use a horrible kludge hack in software! Sometimes it's a noble effort to squeeze all the performance out of the hardware, and sometimes it's the stupid suits' decision. " Don't do it the computer science way, just make it work! The hell with elegance; your other stuff is important and past deadline!" I don't think I've ever seen it fail: do it the wrong way, and it'll always come back to bite you.

@MichaelKarcher Seven Spirits of Ra, however, uses color MAGNIFICENTLY!

@MissUnderstands: The Apple II from the start output pixels at the same 4x chroma rate used by the CGA, and used repeated patterns of four pixels clocked out at that rate to generate the 16 lores colors.  I wouldn't call the CGA's 640x200 composite color mode a "kludge hack", since it's much nicer to program for than the Apple's hi-res or double hires modes.

yes, but the CGA composite trick is most definitely a kludge hack! It's also the coolest way I've seen of extracting extra performance out of computer equipment since increasing the DOS buffers.

@MissUnderstands: If the CGA hadn't included a function to output colorburst in 640x200 mode, I'd view software that programed it for 44 colums by 93 rows and then output an alternating pattern of two pixels on and two off in the first 36 pixels as a kludge hack.  Given that the Apple II established the technique before anyone started design work on the CGA, I'd view the CGA software as exploiting an already well-established technique.

@MissUnderstands composite support wasn’t a hack on CGA, the hardware was designed to allow it.

@StephenKitt I don't think the hardware is specifically built to allow or not to allow it. Unless you mean the dot clock having a specific relation with the colorburst that makes it possible, but using a 14.318 MHz NTSC crystal system clock as the base for dividing it by powers of two to make colorburst and dot clocks is just the most simplest and cheapest way to do it. And you get the stable artifact colours for free.

@Justme it’s conflating things to some extent, but what I had in mind was the RCA connector.

Looking at the gameplay video of Seven Spirits of Ra, it seems this game uses a 100-row text mode, but not at all as 160x100 graphics mode. Instead, it seems the game uses a snow-free 40x100 text mode instead of the 80x100 text mode, and makes good use of different characters, whereas the 160x100 graphics mode only uses the vertically split character at every position.

There were commercial games using 160×100 CGA, although none that were huge successes. Nerdly Pleasures lists the following:

Windmill Software’s Styx, The Exterminator, and Moon Bugs;
Macrocom’s ICON: Quest for the Ring, and The Seven Spirits of RA;
Level 9’s Lancelot, and Scapeghost.

The screenshots you show are from Paku Paku, a Pac-Man clone written in 2011 by Jason M. Knight.
This 160×100 mode was a tweaked text mode, which could explain its obscurity. It required some care to avoid snow on the original IBM PC, and was different to program compared to typical graphics. Gaming on the PC wasn’t hugely popular until EGA and more so VGA, and managing text-mode CGA support alongside graphical EGA/VGA or even as a port from another platform was perhaps too much work for too little gain.

Damn, I love these clean, interesting, information-dense answers. That's why I come here.

On an original IBM CGA or most clones thereof, when using 80-column mode (whether configured for 8 scan lines/row text or 2 lines/row "graphics") attempting to access display memory at any time other than horizontal or vertical retrace would cause the next character sent to the screen to have incorrect colors, an effect commonly called "snow".  Some clone cards and systems would automatically delay attempted access cycles as needed to prevent snow, but systems that could support snow-free access also tended to support better graphics modes anyway.
On a stock 4.77MHz PC, it was possible to do two but not three 160-byte transfers during vertical blank, and one transfer per scan line, without snow.  Transfering a pair of bytes per line would almost work, but sometimes cause a glitch on one of the leftmost two characters even when using the most efficient "wait for horizontal blank" loop possible, with interrupts disabled.  Tweaking DRAM refresh timing would have made it possible to avoid snow when writing a pair of bytes per scan line, but I don't think anyone back in the day did that.
They key point is that even under favorable conditions only about 720 bytes of data (320 during vertical blank, and 200 during other horizontal blanks) can be written per frame, and achieving even half that number would be difficut under more typical conitions (e.g. needing to update non-consecutive bytes of data, and needing to spend some time each frame figuring out what will need to be done during vertical blank).  If one assumes that the time to load a destination address and update five characters' worth of attribute bytes would be 1/16 of the time required to copy five 160 bytes with REP MOVSW, one could perform about 32 such updates per frame--enough for four 8x8 shapes.  It was possible to design games to be playable even given such limitations (e.g. use small objects, and limit how many objects are moving at once), but for most games the faster updates that were possible in higher-resolution modes allowed for better playability.

Another FASCINATING answer! Just one example: "Tweaking DRAM refresh timing would have made it possible to avoid snow when writing." === So DRAM refresh was significant in the PC? It caused a drag on performance? I didn't know that! I thought it happened in the background, or happened so quickly that it didn't really matter.

Yes, it was significant; see chapter 4 of Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book.

@MissUnderstands: Each DRAM refresh had the potential to delay a memory cycle by about a microsecond, once every ~1.5 scan lines if I recall, and when trying to output a word per scan line the second write sometimes happens about a microsecond late.  I would guess that this occasional timing slip is happening because a refresh lands between the last attempt to read retrace status and the consequent memory write.  Programming the refresh so that it happens once per scan line, sometime within the displayed area, would increase the amount of overhead, but keep it from hitting at a bad time.

@MissUnderstands: Actually, if a programs only has to work on 8088 systems which ran at precisely 4.77Mhz (exactly 304 cycles/scan line), it's be possible to output multiple words per scan line using carefully cycle-counted code, again relying upon DRAM refresh timing to be predictable.  Much of the time in the horizontal retrace interval is spent on instructions that need to execute between the IN that fetches retrace status and the actual screen write.  A cycle-counted loop could start transferring data much earlier in the retrace period, and thus transfer more data.

@StephenKitt that graphics book tells everything about 8088 cycle drag. I hd no idea everything was so tight.

As this mode was no documented, it was not well known and as you discovered even supposedly 100% compatible cards often didn't feature it. In a time before the internet and when Bulletin Board Systems tended to be fairly local, it's very likely that most developers simply didn't know about it.
The developers who did know about it would have had commercial considerations. Using an obscure mode that is only guaranteed to work on IBM hardware is going to limit the customer base a lot, and likely result in a lot of returns from people who blame the software rather than their 99% compatible CGA card.

I did mention it's the first mode in the list of IBM documentation of the CGA card, so anyone reading IBM documentation to do any CGA programming would have known about it. With the notes how one would set it up as the BIOS does not set it up for you. And it's CGA specific mode so all CGA cards should be compatible, while EGA cards in native EGA mode aren't, but many of the so called 100% compatible cards could be put into CGA emulation mode.
